# Select Data Frame based on the timerange in R

Tags: r

I have tried to filter data frame based on the time range, I can't able to achieve it. It keeps on result **null** data frame.

[image]

What i have tried so far,

```
 previous_day <- Sys.Date()-1
    last_week <- Sys.Date() -7
    
    count_visit_data$visited_time <- as.Date(count_visit_data$visited_time, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
    
    count_visit_data <- data.table(count_visit_data)
count_visit_data <- count_visit_data[which(count_visit_data$visited_time >= previous_day && count_visit_data$visited_time<= last_week),]
```

Tried other approaches as well:

```
count_visit_data[visited_time %between% c(previous_day, last_week)]
```

Also some other approaches, but didn't get desired. I can't able to figure when am i making wrong.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: I think since `last_week` is less than `previous_day`, you may have the signs reversed. You might want `count_visit_data$visited_time <= previous_day & count_visit_data$visited_time >= last_week` to get rows that are within that time window...also, you might want `&` instead of `&&` for element-wise comparisons...and you might not need `which` as well...

Comment: @Ben I made such a silly mistake, thanks